# I want to replace placeholders in a PDF, can read it out fine, but when I try to edit it, I get EoF error

Tags: python, pdf, error-handling, eof, pypdf

I have a PDF file with spaceholders, that need to be replaced with data from an Excel list. This should not be difficult.

I can read the pdf and find the keywords, but when I try to replace them I always end up with EoF problems. I checked the file, and the EoF code is at the end of it

`0006053835 00000 n  0006055751 00000 n  0006054024 00000 n  0006055774 00000 n  trailer <</Size 1091/Root 1090 0 R/Info 1014 0 R/ID[<937CFAF97C6B065B1AAADAC71CA971E2><937CFAF97C6B065B1AAADAC71CA971E2>]>> startxref 6056146 %%EOF`

I am not sure what causes this error.

```
\Python coding\placeholder.py", line 37, in <module>
    edited_page = PdfReader(BytesIO(page_text.encode('utf-8'))).pages[0]
  File "\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\PyPDF2\_reader.py", line 319, in __init__
    self.read(stream)
  File "\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\PyPDF2\_reader.py", line 1415, in read
    self._find_eof_marker(stream)
  File "\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\PyPDF2\_reader.py", line 1471, in _find_eof_marker
    raise PdfReadError("EOF marker not found")
PyPDF2.errors.PdfReadError: EOF marker not found
```

Here is the code

```
import pandas as pd
from PyPDF2 import PdfReader, PdfWriter
from io import BytesIO
import chardet

# Path to the Excel file containing placeholder data
excel_filename = "prozesse-220-238.xlsx"

# Read the Excel data
df_excel = pd.read_excel(excel_filename)

# Path to the PDF file
pdf_filename = "handbook-2-with-placeholder.pdf"
pdf_reader = PdfReader(pdf_filename)

# Initialize a BytesIO object for the PDF
output = BytesIO()

# Iterate through all rows in the Excel and search for keywords in the PDF
for _, row in df_excel.iterrows():
    found_keywords = []
    for column_name, value in row.items():
        if str(value) in pdf_reader.pages[0].extract_text():
            found_keywords.append(column_name)
    
    page_text = pdf_reader.pages[0].extract_text()
    for keyword in found_keywords:
        page_text = page_text.replace("{" + keyword + "}", str(row[keyword]))
    
    # Determine the encoding of the PDF
    result = chardet.detect(page_text.encode())
    encoding = result['encoding']
    
    # Create a PdfWriter object and add the edited page
    pdf_writer = PdfWriter()
    pdf_writer.add_page(pdf_reader.pages[0])
    edited_page = PdfReader(BytesIO(page_text.encode(encoding))).pages[0]
    pdf_writer.add_page(edited_page)
    
    # Write the edited page to the output file object
    pdf_writer.write(output)

# Save the created PDF
edited_pdf_filename = "edited_handbook.pdf"
with open(edited_pdf_filename, "wb") as edited_pdf_file:
    edited_pdf_file.write(output.getvalue())

print("Edited PDF has been saved:", edited_pdf_filename)
```

Since the error is related to 37, I tried to go with a specific coding and without. (utf8). I have no idea what causes this error or how to avoid it.

I expected it to work right away, but I tried with a few different libraries and code I found online, but I am most confident in this version. I tried working with a specific coding (utf8) and without, but neither worked.

I used chardet to determine the coding type but it was inconclusive.

```
import chardet

pdf_filename = "handbook-2-with-placeholder.pdf"

with open(pdf_filename, 'rb') as pdf_file:
    raw_data = pdf_file.read()
    result = chardet.detect(raw_data)
    print("Detected encoding:", result['encoding'])
```

`Detected encoding: None`

Comment: Reading a PDF in order to edit it is perhaps not how I would go about this. I think it can be done, but could the static data be held in a more convenient format? For example, having the template in HTML, and then rendering to PDF would be rather easier.

Comment: I can try that, but this seems like thinking around the corner to me. Will see now if it works, I'll be back with an edit.

Comment: @halfer I am struggling with conversion to html or word, as I always seem to lose data, formatting or images on the way. Hence why I want to work directly in the pdf. I don't understand why that is so difficult. I only need to repace a few placeholders, I am not trying anything crazy.

Comment: I consider PDF to be a write-only format. I suspect re-writing one can be made to work, but I personally would not do what you are doing. I appreciate that if you have tried your approach for a long time, moving to a new approach feels like wasting a major sunk cost. On the other hand, you may find alternatives much easier.

Comment: I would suggest trying any of three approaches: (1) HTML/CSS with wkhtmltopdf, Pandoc, or maybe a commercial tool like PrinceXML; (2) Inkscape (which uses XML in its file format) which can render directly to SVG or PDF; (3) Scribus, which again would render to PDF. I can't recall the document format, but I would expect it to be open source.

Comment: (I recall that PrinceXML is very expensive for a server license, but when I used it many years ago, it was much better at CSS rendering than the alternatives).